# Integrate a function defined by other Integrals

Tags: numerical-integration

I have an expression of this kind

```
NIntegrate[ Exp[-W^2/2] NIntegrate[Exp[-h^2/2](Cosh[W+h])^0.3 h Tanh[W+h],{h,-\[Infinity],+\[Infinity]}] / NIntegrate[Exp[-h^2/2] (Cosh[W+h])^0.3 ,{h,-\[Infinity],+\[Infinity]}]    ,{W,-\[Infinity],+\[Infinity]}]
```

in which the function I want to integrate is itself a numerical integral depending on the variable of the external variable W.

Is there an automatic way to evaluate numerically such expressions in Mathematica?

I have written a program in C in which I solve this problem creating two arrays solving pointwise the inner integrals for many values of W (the variable of the external integral) and then using these arrays to perform the external integral. I wanted to check the result in Mathematica, but I cannot find an alternative (and possibly simpler!) way to do it in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
f[W_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
   Exp[-h^2/2] (Cosh[W + h])^0.3 h Tanh[W + h], {h, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]/
  NIntegrate[Exp[-h^2/2] (Cosh[W + h])^0.3, {h, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]

NIntegrate[Exp[-W^2/2]*f[W], {W, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]
```

Comment: it seems exactly what I needed! can you briefly explain the syntax and why it works? Thanks

Comment: @psmith I first made a `SetDelay` of the product of the two integrals and then called it in the third integral.